# How do I dynamically insert NULL into a postgres table?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, null

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE test(a int, b int);
```

The values to the table are inserted from dynamic input

$a, $b (PHP variables)

```
$query = "UPDATE test set a=$a where b = $b";
pg_query($db, $query);
```

This doesn't work when $a is empty (i.e when the user doesn't enter any value for a form field from the table). How to I get around this?

Comment: Did you try `set a='$a'`? If $a is empty, it will attempt to insert an empty value. If your table accepts null values, it should work.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: `NULL` and *empty* `''` are very different values.

Comment: Oh I see. I haven't been working with PgSQL for a while so pardon my ignorance. I just meant that, when fetched in the php, if you compare it with `if (!$value)` both would be parsed as false.

Answer (score 3):

Test if `$a` is empty and if so set it to null:

```
$a = ($a == '') ? 'NULL' : "'$a'";
$query = "UPDATE test set a=$a where b='$b'";
```

Don't forget to quote the `$b` value, it was returning an error here until I quoted it.

I added quotation to `$a` in the check above if it's not null, so it will now work if $a is either NULL (empty), an integer or string.

Comment: In postgres a='' throws an error. I have to explicitly set it to $a= null but I dont know how to dynamically pass null. I can pass 'null' with the quotes but not just null.

Comment: I edited my answer. I'll setup a table on my PG server to test it meanwhile.

Comment: It was returning an error until I quoted the $b in `where b='$b'`, try it now.

Comment: I finished editing it now, give it a try. `NULL` shouldn't be quoted otherwise it'll be inserted as a literal string, so I added quotation to `$a` when it's not null in the check above.

Comment: No still doesn't work. I get invalid input syntax for type double prescision: "NULL" the query text goes like this update test set a = 'NULL' where b = '2';

Comment: I created my table with varchar accepting null values, ok I'll create a table with your 2 int fields to check.

Comment: I just did a `UPDATE test set a=NULL where b='2'` in the table generated with your SQL in the first post and it worked just fine. Make sure your field is accepting null values. Also, you can try putting a `die($query);` right after the `$query` line to make sure it looks like the one I just posted in this comment. Maybe I'm just too sleepy to notice something really obvious..

Comment: NULL shouldn't be quoted by the way. with the `$a` and `$query` declared in my answer it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

If $a is empty, `$query` will look like:

```
UPDATE test SET a= where b = whatever
```

You need to explicitly add `NULL` to the query string:

```
UPDATE test SET a=NULL where b = whatever
```